# Using Typekit fonts in Redactor

Tags: redactor

I need to use a Typekit font in Redactor, but I'm not quite sure if I've done something wrong, or if Redactor's made a breaking change.

I'm enabling the `iframe = true` parameter in a `custom.json` redactor config, and then loading Typekit with the `initCallback` parameter. However, Redactor isn't placing the iframe (as of Craft Pro 2.4.2691) that Typekit uses for selection purposes.

Any ideas? has Redactor recently made a breaking change?

**TL;DR:** What's the best-practice for using Typekit fonts in Redactor fields as of Craft Pro 2.4.2691?

Answer (score 1):

I would try to add the fonts with the Craft plugins

[Control Panel JS](https://github.com/lindseydiloreto/craft-cpjs)
[Control Panel CSS](https://github.com/lindseydiloreto/craft-cpcss)

Comment: While that would work, it wouldn't be future-proof, since I'd need to explicitly tell the Plugin what pages have Redactor. It'd also be somewhat overkill to add a plugin for something Redactor already (supposedly) has support for.

Comment: Using Redactor sparse? Or what's the reason to not trigger that JS on every CP request (to preload/cache the fonts)?